# Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences

The Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence says that for a short exact sequence $$1 \to G \to H \to K \to 1 \quad (1)$$ of (discrete) groups, we have a first quadrant spectral sequence with $E_2$ page
$$E_2^{pq} = H^p(K;H^q(G;\mathbb Z))$$ converging to $H^{\ast}(H;\mathbb Z)$. We can think of this spectral sequence as the usual Serre spectral sequence of the fiber seqeuence
$$BG \to BH \to BK$$ which induces an action of $\pi_1(BK) = K$ on $H^q(BG)$, i.e. we can see $H^q(G)$ as a system of local coefficients. My question is: Is there also a purely algebraic description of the $K$-module structure on $H^{\ast}(G)$? In particular, what happens if the seqeunce $(1)$ splits? Is the $K$-module structrue on $H^{\ast}(G)$ then induced from the action of $K$ on $G$?

Comment: This is found in the standard book on group cohomology, by Ken Brown. In particular, yes, it's the usual structure (given in Chapter III.8.2 of that book).

Comment: $H$ acts on $G$ by conjugation. This produces an action of $H$ on $H^*(G)$ which restricts to the trivial action on $G\subset H$. Hence the action factors through the natural projection $H\twoheadrightarrow K$. In particular, the answer to your final question is yes.